# Template module names based on position

Tags: module, templates, positions

For instance, if I have a position called 'position-1' and I've multiple modules in position-1. How can I get all module names based on position (in this case 'position-1')? Is it even possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean programatically, JModuleHelper should return the info you need.

```
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('position-1');
print_r($modules);
```

Comment: What I get is - https://img.exs.lv/e/z/ezeliitis/Untitled_4.png

Shouldn't I fetch two objects instead of only one?

Comment: It should return an array of all the modules in that position. I've tested it both on a template and a module.  Curious that the object it returns for you has an ID of 0 when they usually start at 1?  Are you creating/assigning modules via the module manager?

Comment: No, I do it like this: <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-3" style="xhtml" />

Comment: How are you assigning modules to that position, though?  You seem to have a module position and a module which are both called position-3 - there may just be conflicts in your naming.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to know which modules are assigned to a specific template position, simple go to *Extensions->Modules*, then click *Search Tools* and then specifie the disired position in the *Select Position* select box. Hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Not exactly. I want to do it through program code (Using PHP). I have custom template (maybe this makes things clear).

I thought Joomla have some way to get module parameters (in this case name/title) of specific position.